# Reverse for 'user-profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I'm watching a course, and after the lecturer used `exclude = ['host', 'participants']` in `Meta class` I got this error, which highlights this line in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'user-profile' room.host.id %}">@{{room.host.username}}</a>
```

view:

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    rooms = user.room_set.all()
    room_messages = user.message_set.all()
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    context = {'user': user, 'rooms': rooms,
               'room_messages': room_messages,
               'topics': topics,
               'pk': pk}
    return render(request, 'base/profile.html', context)
```

urls:

```
path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.userProfile, name='user-profile'),
```

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank=True)
```

I tried to remove `exclude = ['host']`, but it did not help.
Then I tried to add `'pk': pk` to `context` in `userProfile`, but it also did not help. I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Is room a context in your template?

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, that is great, but please don't add things like "FIXED" to the question title, or edit a solution into your **question**. Instead, post an **answer** with the fix in sufficient detail and accept it after the timeout.

Comment: Thx for advice. I should post solution in cooment like this?